# Non-uniformly continous function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, continuity, uniform-continuity

I have found a topic here (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/uniformly-continuous-function) in Theorem 3.3.10 that: There is a continuous function $f$ on $[0, 1]$ which is unbounded, and
therefore not uniformly continuous.

Anyone, please help me to understand it.

Comment: A continuos function is allways bounded in a compact set.

Comment: I also know that but this result is intriguing.

Comment: A continuous function at the compact $ [0,1] $ is necessarily bounded.

Comment: I find $0=1$ intriguing.

Comment: The author is not working in the "usual" axiom system I believe [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_analysis) and [this](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Realizability) are relevant here.

Answer (score -1):

The proof you link defines

> Let $(I_n)_n$ be a covering of $[0, 1]$ by open intervals $(r_n, s_n)$ (...)

and then it says

> But by the property of this cover, it follows that no finite part of it covers [0, 1]

Which is false: every open cover of $[0,1]$ has finite subcover, because $[0, 1]$ is compact. The proof is just wrong.

Comment: This is true in ZFC, but the article is asking about constructive analysis.